# Payflow Pro module for Satchmo?

Tags: module, satchmo, payflowpro

So i built my first eCommerce website and am approved for the merchant account. However they want me to use Payflow Pro and there are no modules made for it in Satchmo.

Does anyone have a module for Payflow Pro?

If not how do i go about creating one? I am not very experienced with this stuff and this is my first time using Python Django ever.

Answer (score 1):

There's this here: https://github.com/jiaaro/satchmo-payflow-pro-express-checkout

and I'll figure out if I need to make one for the HTTP interface using this: https://github.com/bkeating/python-payflowpro

You might want to watch whether I start working on one here: https://github.com/Lacrymology but I'm not sure yet

EDIT: Final module [PayFlow Pro for Satchmo](https://bitbucket.org/chris1610/satchmo/changeset/4b04a29fe9f9) written by Lacrymology has been merged to Satchmo.

Comment: Lacrymology **committed** his solution to Satchmo trunk this montth.